# Does Scala even have statements?

Tags: scala

The difference seems to very different between the two compared to other languages like C or C++. Things that could be statements in C seem to be expressions in Scala. How should I differentiate them, and any reason why it’s like that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please give an example of how a statement in C is considered an expression in Scala. Also, I'd suggest removing "even" from the title, since the tone doesn't seem neutral

Answer (score 2):

According to Scala Language Specification, it does have statements:

> [Statements occur as parts of blocks and templates. A statement can be an import, a definition or an expression, or it can be empty. Statements used in the template of a class definition can also be declarations.](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#statements)

C++ also has expression statements and declaration statements; the main difference is that it also has additional types of statements, and their equivalents are generally expressions in Scala, so they can be used either as expression statements or as part of larger expressions.